# Conditionally include folder in deployment

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, release, release-management

I have a setup project that I created in Visual Studio.  I want to conditionally include/exclude a particular folder and its contents based on the build configuration.  What I have in mind is:

```
'$(Configuration)' == 'Release (Special)'
```

I tried setting the "Condition" property of the folder, and even of each and every file contained therein, but to no avail.  This property seems to have a different use.  So then, how can I accomplish this?

The second part of my question is then, how can I also conditionally (the same condition) include a shortcut in the `User's Programs Menu` folder which points to a file that's within the conditionally-included folder.

Comment: Could you post the relevant portions of the target you are running that exhibit the symptoms?  It is likely that you just have the `Condition` attribute on the wrong element.

Comment: Inside VS2010 I just selected the folders/files then pasted the above condition into the "Condition" property.  Keep in mind that this is the "Condition" property on a folder/file in a setup project which I think differs from the "Condition" property on a referenced assembly in a C# project.

Comment: It would help to know what Visual Studio is doing to your project file (which should just be XML) whenever you make that change via the IDE.

Comment: The setup project file is not XML.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with setup projects (big surprise eh?). Is the project file at least human readable?  I think your MSBuild tag might be confusing as that tool definitely works with XML files.